# Get sql query from powerbi report/dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

can I get SQL query used to create a dataset in PowerBI using the powerbi report/dataset. I no longer have the desktop file (.pbix).

I only have the report and dataset in PowerBI Service. I had used couple of joins and a couple of where conditions in powerBI desktop. I am trying to recreate the dataset but now I somehow get slightly different version of the dataset.

Can I find the joined tables and where conditions used in the powerBI desktop via the report in powerBI service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have full access to the dataset in the workspace, if so, you can simply locate the dataset, click the three dots and download the file.

[image]

Then you can simply navigate to Power Query and locate the M code and retrieve the SQL Statement.

Other that, there's no really easy way to get it, you can also try these methods:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-capture-sql-queries-generated-by-power-bi-fc20a94d4b08

Very Alternatively, you can check Power BI REST API, to get the dataset's information and data sources [(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-datasources)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-datasources) and then ask the admin of the DB to mine the query that leads to the report directly from  SQL Database admin panel.